# Get the all data for the max row mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get data only for the max row for my table say table m

```
id  labref  activity
---------------------
1    x       ab
2    x       cd
3    x       ef
4    y       jk
5    y       il
```

When I run

```
SELECT max(id), labref, activity FROM table m GROUP BY labref
```

it returns: Result(1)-Wrong

```
id     labref   activity
-------------------------
3       x        ab
5       y        jk
```

but what i need is: Result(2)-Right

```
id     labref   activity
-------------------------
3       x        ef
5       y        il
```

Note that it brings max id but returns the first value for the activity and not the value of activity in the max row, how do i achieve the second result

Comment: A good-rule-of-thumb (actually a 'legal' requirement on other RDBMSs) is to always GROUP BY all the non-aggregated columns referenced in the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using `left join`

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
left join table_name t2 on t1.labref = t2.labref
and t1.id < t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

There are many other ways to do this but left join and Uncorrelated subs-query are considered to be better in terms of performance

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: before giving solution you should see other answers @Abhik. :) because PO will confuse when he/she will see exact same two answers..!

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia the time says my answer came 6 mins ago, hope you checked yours before adding the comment above.

Comment: OK. Sure. My mistake.. Removing my answer :)

Comment: Thanks guys that just did it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT max(id), labref, activity 
FROM table 
WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM table) 
m GROUP BY labref
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause is drawing from the entire table and not constrained by the `GROUP BY`. So it will only show the result for the lab ref which happens to have the `MAX(id)` for the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.labref, a.activity
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.labref, MAX(a.id) 
            FROM tableA a 
            GROUP BY a.labref
           ) b ON a.labref = b.labref AND a.id = b.id
```